# Object is of type 'unknown'.ts

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm trying TypeScript by creating a Redux store with Redux Tooklit.

Here is my `redux.js` file :

```
import { configureStore, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const testSlice = createSlice({
  name: "test",
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    callApi: (state, action) => {
      const getData = {
        type: "test/getData",
        data: action.payload
      };

      state.push(getData);
    }
  }
});

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    test: testSlice.reducer
  }
})
```

Here is my `index.tsx` file :

```
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';
import { store } from './redux'

const container = document.getElementById('root')!;
const root = createRoot(container);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

And finaly, my component `Login.tsx` file :

```
[...]
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

[...]
const test = useSelector((state) => state.test);
[...]
```

In `Login.tsx`, VSCode underline `state` in red, and says :

```
Object is of type 'unknown'
```

I tried to tell TypeScript what kind of type to expect like this : `const test = useSelector((state: Object) => state.test);` but I get an error saying that `test` is not an object. Same try with Array.

I'm a bit lost. Can anyone explain me where is my mistake and how to fix this ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are correctly thinking you need to give a type to the *state* so that it doesn't get the default *unknown* type. However, instead of using the *Object* type you should use a custom one that correctly represents your whole state. You can create one by adding this in your `redux.js` file:

```
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
```

Then, from your `Login.tsx` file you can do:

```
const test = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.test);
```

More official docs here: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/quick-start#add-slice-reducers-to-the-store

Answer (score 1):

You can add this line od code to redux.js file

```
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
```

Then you can use this type in useSelector hook

```
const test = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.test);
```